# .net 4.0 Reflection convert object to specific type

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

My problem is quite simple 
Suppose I have those class:

```
public class A
{
    public Collection<B> B { get; set; }
    public Collection<C> C { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int IntB { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string StringC { get; set; }
}
```

And I write a function:

```
public void GetValue(string fieldName){
        A a = new A();
        PropertyInfo infor = typeof(A).GetProperty(fieldName);
        object obj = infor.GetValue(a,null);
}
```

My question is how can I turn obj to corresponding Collection, in this case is `Collection<B>` or `Collection<C>`, depending in fieldName value 
Thank in advance

Comment: May I ask you why do you use reflection instead of direct access to the property? In your example you could just do a.B, but I suppose this is not possible in your real scenario.

Comment: I want to create a function that input is field name in string, so I need to use reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast it:

```
var collection = (Collection<B>)(infor.GetValue(a,null));
```

EDIT:

if you use LINQ on the resulting collections, you may want to use OfType (link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) and/or Cast (link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)
Like

```
var collection = getCollection(a,null));
collection.OfType<B>.Select(b => b.IntB)....
```

Comment: First thank for your fast response, and so sorry for missing the point in my question. Could please you help me again?

Comment: I read that you want to use them for passing them to Linq.. I see several options here: you may do a supertype "Parent", and have B and C inherit from it, and return always a Colletion<Parent>. Or return a plain COllection (and cast to it) and then use the OfType<T> or Cast<T> extension methods in your LINQ code. Would that work for you?

Comment: I could help you better if you post an example LINQ call you want to do on your collections

Comment: Thank for your great support. The problems turn out quite simple :). I just convert it to IEnumerable<object> and use Linq on it

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a statically typed object in your method when you determine the property that will be called at runtime. But the runtime time of `obj` is of the actual type of your property.

Comment: I need to call some function in this class, in this case Linq. Do you have any solution for it?